# Fire event from objective C to Titanium using Hyperloop

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to fire event from objective C to Titanium using hyperloop.

I found how to do that from Titanium iOS module : https://ti-qa-archive.github.io/question/51751/how-to-fire-an-event-in-a-module-and-catch-it-in-js.html.

The documentation states "TiModule is a subclass of TiProxy which provides the fireEvent methods" but TiModule is not present in my class.

The interface in my .h file implements UIViewController instead of TiModule or TiProxy. 
Thank you

Comment: did you follow https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Development+Guide? especially the `iOS Module Architecture` part talks about event handling

Comment: yes ,but this guide is for module creation and event handling and I am dealing with Hyperloop and pods here.I don't understand how to trigger event from Objective C class to titanium.

Comment: did you follow the hyperloop guides and check out hyperloop examples on github?